# How do I search a double array using JTextField input?

Tags: arrays, double, jtextfield

I have a double array where I need to search the first row using a jtextfield input to get the index (position of [i]), then use that index number to identify the second row location and use the variable in the second array row. I'm using this to get the Gross Profit Margin Multiplier in second row of the array based on the position of the percentage margin in the first row array.

Do appreciate your help. I have searched other array links but they deal ether with the locations and not the contents of the locations.

public void getMarginArray(){

```
 double[][] margn = {{10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33,34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50},
                {1.11, 1.12, 1.13,  1.15, 1.16, 1.17, 1.19, 1.20, 1.22, 1.23, 1.25, 1.26, 1.28, 1.30, 1.31, 1.33, 1.35, 1.37, 1.39, 1.41, 1.43, 1.45, 1.47, 1.49, 1.51, 1.55, 1.56, 1.59, 1.61, 1.64, 1.67, 1.70, 1.72, 1.75, 1.79, 1.82, 1.86, 1.89, 1.92, 1.96, 2.00}};

            Double MARG = Double.parseDouble( jtxtfldMargin.getText());
            Double MAR1;
            for (int i=0; i<margn.length; i++){


            if (margn[0][i] ==MARG){
               Double MAR1=margn[1][i]; 
               System.out.println(margn[0][i]);
               System.out.println(margn[1][i]);
               System.out.println(MAR1);
            };

            };
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get what I needed by changing to two separate arrays. Now when the first array matches the text field, the location is used for the second array to get the multiplier:

public void getMarginArray(){

```
    double[] doubleArray1 = {10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33,34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50};
    double[] doubleArray2  =  {1.11, 1.12, 1.13,  1.15, 1.16, 1.17, 1.19, 1.20, 1.22, 1.23, 1.25, 1.26, 1.28, 1.30, 1.31, 1.33, 1.35, 1.37, 1.39, 1.41, 1.43, 1.45, 1.47, 1.49, 1.51, 1.55, 1.56, 1.59, 1.61, 1.64, 1.67, 1.70, 1.72, 1.75, 1.79, 1.82, 1.86, 1.89, 1.92, 1.96, 2.00};
          Double MARG = Double.parseDouble( jtxtfldMargin.getText());
          Double margMult;


              for(int i = 0; i<doubleArray1.length; i++){
                for(int j = 0; j<doubleArray2.length;j++){

            if(doubleArray1[i] == MARG ){
                margMult = doubleArray2[i];
                System.out.println(margMult);
                          }
                     }
                  }

    }
```